# SPARQL - get all the companies along with their description

Tags: sparql, wikipedia

I would like to get wikipedia data about all the companies listed there, along with their description/ summary. Any extra data would be also appreciated - do you know where I can check the columns I could possibly retrieve?
[https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%0A%3Fcompany%20%3FcompanyLabel%20%3Fisin%20%3Fweb%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fdescription%0A%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcompany%20.%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ783794.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP946%20%3Fisin.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Fweb.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP571%20%3Finception.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry.%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%0A%3Fcompany%20%3FcompanyLabel%20%3Fisin%20%3Fweb%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fdescription%0A%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcompany%20.%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ783794.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP946%20%3Fisin.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Fweb.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP571%20%3Finception.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcompany%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry.%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010)

```
SELECT
?company ?companyLabel ?web ?countryLabel ?description

WHERE 
{
     ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
     ?article schema:about ?company . 

     ?company p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q783794.

     ?company wdt:P946 ?isin. 
     OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P856 ?web.}
     OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P571 ?inception.}
     OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P17 ?country.}

     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
} LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to browse/search applicable properties, you could use the [Wikidata Property Explorer](https://prop-explorer.toolforge.org/). It has an entry for "Wikidata property for items about organizations":

[image: Showing properties that have 'employ' in their label]

To find which properties are actually used in the graph, you could use SPARQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property

WHERE  {

  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> . 
  ?article schema:about ?company . 

  ?company p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q783794 .

  ?company ?property [] .

} 
LIMIT 10
```

For performance reasons, it might be preferable to do this only for selected companies (which you can add to / remove from `VALUES`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property

WHERE {

  VALUES ?company {
    wd:Q230343
    wd:Q588001
    wd:Q673632
    # …
  }

  ?company ?property [] .

} 
LIMIT 50
```